# For loop for storing value in many different matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have written a code that stores data in a matrix, but I want to shorten it so it iterates over itself.
The number of matrices created is the known variable. If it was 3, the code would be:

```
for i = 1:31
    if idx(i) == 1
        C1 = [C1; Output2(i,:)];
    end
    if idx(i) == 2
        C2 = [C2; Output2(i,:)];
    end
    if idx(i) == 3
        C3 = [C3; Output2(i,:)];
    end
end
```

Comment: What language are you using?  MATLIB?

Comment: Soeey matlab, fixed it.

Comment: Normally I would suggest a cell array here, any reason why you do not use that? `eval` may be used, but using a cell array instead is recommended by mathworks.

Answer (score 0):

As patrik said in the comments, naming variables like this is poor practice. You would be better off using cell arrays `M{1}=C1`, or if all the `Ci` are the same size, even just a 3D array `M`, for example, where `M(:,:,1)=C1`.

If you really want to use `C1`, `C2`, ... as you variable names, I think you will have to use `eval`, as arielnmz mentioned. One way to do this in matlab is

```
for i=1:3
    eval(['C' num2str(idx(i)) '=[C' num2str(idx(i)) ';Output2(' num2str(i) ',:)];'])
end
```

---

Edited to add test code:

```
idx=[2 1 3 2 2 3];

Output2=rand(6,4);

C1a=[];
C2a=[];
C3a=[];
for i = 1:length(idx)
    if idx(i) == 1
        C1a = [C1a; Output2(i,:)];
    end
    if idx(i) == 2
        C2a = [C2a; Output2(i,:)];
    end
    if idx(i) == 3
        C3a = [C3a; Output2(i,:)];
    end
end

C1=[];
C2=[];
C3=[];
for i=1:length(idx)
    eval(['C' num2str(idx(i)) '=[C' num2str(idx(i)) ';Output2(' num2str(i) ',:)];'])
end

all(C1a(:)==C1(:))
all(C2a(:)==C2(:))
all(C3a(:)==C3(:))
```

Comment: This does unfortually not do the same as the example in the question. Sorry but -1 :(

Comment: Ok then I will remove the -1, but you should definitely edit your code. It makes no sense to have an `idx`, where all values are unique, since this is not the case in the question. It gives the inpression that you loop over the unique indices and not the index vector

Comment: @patrik Oh I see. I blame OP for being incredibly vague! I think it works as OP intended now, but it's definitely not the best way to do something like this!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract rows from Output2 into new variables based on idx values? If so, you can do as follows:

```
Output2 = rand(5, 10); % example

idx = [1,1,2,2,3];

% get rows from Output which numbers correspond to those in idx with given value
C1 = Output2(find(idx==1),:);
C2 = Output2(find(idx==2),:);
C3 = Output2(find(idx==3),:);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Marcin i have another solution. Here i predefine `my_C` as a cell array. Output2 and idx are random generated and instead of find i just use logical adressing. You have to convert the data to type cell `{}`

```
Output2 = round(rand(31,15)*10);
idx = uint8(round(1+rand(1,31)*2));
my_C = cell(1,3);
my_C(1,1) = {Output2(idx==1,:)};
my_C(1,2) = {Output2(idx==2,:)};
my_C(1,3) = {Output2(idx==3,:)};
```

If you want to get your data back just use e.g. `my_C{1,1}` for the first group.

If you have not 3 but n resulting matrices you can use:

```
    Output2 = round(rand(31,15)*10);
    idx = uint8(round(1+rand(1,31)*(n-1)));
    my_C = cell(1,n);
for k=1:n
    my_C(1,k) = {Output2(idx==k,:)};
end
```

Where n is a positive integer number

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a slighty different approach. Except for making the rest of the code more maintainable it may also slightly speed up the execution. This due to that matlab uses a JIT compiler and `eval` must be recompiled every time. Try this:

```
nMatrices = 3
for k = 1:nMatrices
    C{k} = Output2(idx==k,:);
end
```